# Integral of trig fraction using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I'm getting to grips with the process of integration by substitution, and would like to ask for feedback on my calculation:

$$\int{\frac{\cos{x}}{\sqrt{1+2\sin{x}}}}\,\,dx$$
Let
$$u=2\sin{x},\,\,\frac{du}{dx} = 2\cos{x},\,\,du=2\cos{x}\,dx$$
So
$$\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u}}}\,\,du = \frac{1}{2}\cdot2\sqrt{1+u}+c$$
$$=\sqrt{1+u}+c$$

Substitute $2\sin{x}$ back into the equation:
$$=\sqrt{1+2\sin{x}}+c$$

Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: You can check your integration by differentiating the answer $\sqrt{1+2\sin{x}}+c$

Comment: your result is correct